# Top third, next third of items by sales

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet as shown below. I need to get the top third/ next third items by sales count. Is there a way to get this done in Excel?

```
  Item    Count
  1         100
  2          90
  3          80
  4          60
  5          55
  6          50
  7          45
  8          35
  9          25
```

Dividing into 3 buckets, so 540/3 = ~180 items in each –

Bucket 1 – Items 1 and 2 (Count = 190)
Bucket  2 – Items 3, 4 and 5 (Count = 195)
Bucket 3 -  Items 6, 7, 8, 9 (Count = 155)

Comment: There's a way to do almost anything computational in Excel. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. Assuming that your `Item` and `Count` data are in columns A and B, then the shortest path is to use the following formula in cell `C2`:

```
=ROUND(3*SUM($B$2:$B2)/SUM($B$2:$B$10),0)
```

After entering that into `C2`, select that cell and drag down the right-bottom corner of the cell all the way to the last row. Note the `$` sign that is "missing" on purpose before the second `2`. That takes care of the auto-fill behavior needed when dragging down the corner.

If you are allowed to use a helper column, you can create a computationally more efficient method using following layout:

[image: Example layout to implement the buckets]

If you want to, you can hide column `C`. It contains cumulative values of the different sales counts. Cell `C1` is set to `0`, cell `C2` contains the formula `=$C1+$B2`. Column `D` then approximates the buckets by using the formula `=ROUND(3*$C2/$C$10,0)` in cell `D2`, and then again dragging down the bottom-right corner. This might be the better approach if you have many rows on your sheet.

Note that both solutions yield the same results. The value in one or more buckets could become `0`, which is not exactly right. That can be avoided using `ROUNDUP` in stead of `ROUND`, but since you have not indicated clearly where you want the boundaries of the buckets to fall exactly in different situations, I thought I leave that as an exercise to you :-).